# DataReader.Read() returning empty

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sqldatareader

i essentially have a query that generates a list of items (column 1) and their descriptions (column 2). There are 3 different items (out of 170) that do not have a description, so i hard coded my program to adjust for those 3 items. However, whenever my reader gets to the first item that has a null column, the reader is not even able to read the Item. Instead it says "Enumeration Yielded No Results"

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var node = reader[0] as string;
    string fullNodeName = string.Empty; 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)reader[1]))
    {
        switch ((string)reader[0])
        {
            case "xxx":
                fullNodeName = "jhhfgnfh";
                break;
            case "xxx":
                fullNodeName = "fhnfgndfgdh";
                break;
            case "xxx":
                fullNodeName = "werqrqwerq";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fullNodeName = reader[1] as string;
    }
    _nodeTokenList.Add(new Carriers.NodeToken(node, string.Format("{0} - {1}", node, fullNodeName)));

}
```

the data looks something like

```
Node   Description

XXX  ||  YYYYYYY YYY YYY

XXX  ||  YYYYYYY YYY YYY

XXX  || YYYYYYY YYY YYY

XXX  ||  YYYYYYY YYY YYY

XXX  ||                

XXX  ||  YYYYYYY YYY YYY
```

the row with the null description field is when the program starts acting up. Whats weird is that it enters the while loop for this row, but the exception gets caught at var node = reader[0] as string; (the field that is NOT null)

Comment: Please pay more attention to code formatting when you ask a question. Most of your code was indented miles over, making it much harder to read. Before posting, always read over what you're about to post and ask yourself whether it's formatted the way you'd want to read it if you were trying to answer.

Comment: thanks, will keep in mind

Comment: "Enumeration Yielded No Results" sounds like a debugger message. What happens when you actually run the code?

Comment: It captures all of the members up until the row with the empty field then it throws an exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'."} ...the yieleded no results is what is stored in the reader when i inspected the variable

Comment: Why switch ((string)reader[0]) when you have node variable already, and why reader.Read(); before while loop?

Comment: Right - that exception message is what should be in your question, and the line that's throwing the exception is `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)reader[1]))`.

Comment: essentially i need to be able to tell the reader, hey there may be a null field, read it anyway

Comment: But `reader[1]` will return DbNull.Value if the value is null. You can't cast that to a string.

Comment: You have to check DBNull before convert to string

Comment: @tony...i am switching because those are the 3 that do not have a description... and the first read() was a typo, removing it doesnt fix my problem

Comment: @tony, why is it not reading the first value and triggering DBNull for the null field?

Comment: if (reader[0] != System.DBNull.Value))
{
           node=reader[0].ToString();
}  and you have to do the same with reader[1]

Comment: Why are you doing a `reader.Read()` before  your `while` loop?  That's skipping the first row, did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap out the `(string)reader[1]` with `Convert.ToString(reader[1])`. It contains a `DBNull` value, not `null`, and casting to `string` is what is causing your error. The `Convert` class can handle conversion better:

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var node = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
    string fullNodeName = string.Empty; 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(reader[1])))
    {
        switch ((string)reader[0])
        {
            case "xxx":
                fullNodeName = "jhhfgnfh";
                break;
            case "xxx":
                fullNodeName = "fhnfgndfgdh";
                break;
            case "xxx":
                fullNodeName = "werqrqwerq";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fullNodeName = reader[1] as string;
    }
    _nodeTokenList.Add(new Carriers.NodeToken(node, string.Format("{0} - {1}", node, fullNodeName)));

}
```

Comment: I like this answer but the exception is getting triggered 2 lines above, with var node  = reader[0]

Comment: Updated, just use `Convert.ToString()` again on the convert of `reader[0]`.